# make an image link to each portfolio item in wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, php-5.3

I am using a **filterable plugin** for portfolio items. This is the part of the code that display the thumbnail of each portfolio item and the title of the post. The link when is pressed is opens the image bigger but I would want that link to go to each portfolio item corresponding to the image thumbnail.

What would I have to modify?

```
 <div class="view view-first  <?php ps_the_terms(); ?>">
     <?php ps_post_thumb(array(400,300)); ?>
     <div class="mask">
         <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
         <p><?php echo ps_post_excerpt(80); ?></p>
         <a  rel="colorbox" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="">View Details &nbsp;&nbsp;+</a>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a  rel="colorbox" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="">View Details &nbsp;&nbsp;+</a>
```

Remove `rel="colorbox"` as that's probably what the JavaScript is using for a hook.

You may also need to change `<?php the_permalink(); ?>` if that doesn't already go to the portfolio item.

Comment: I know that I have to change the_permalink but with what?

Answer (score 0):

If the permalink is not using the post link try:

```
 <?php echo post_permalink( $ID ); ?>
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_permalink

Comment: in the code `the_title()` is used, does it return the title of the post? Did you remove the colorbox reference?

Comment: yes..it returns the title of the post..i removed also the reference but still nothing..the link goes to the full image..